# Winform loading an Image via an TCP message

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp

I'm trying to have an image load in my winform through a TCP message.

At the moment I have a my program set to look in the required directory via the following. This line is held with in a TCP class I've set up:

```
Image _imageName = Image.FromFile("C:\\Image\\");
```

What my tcp command will do is send the following string line:

```
IMG Cat
```

The first 3 letters aren't important, but need to be in there. With this tcp command I've set up a switch statement that will act depending on those first three letters. So, my new _image name line looks like the following:

```
Image _imageName = Image.FromFile("C:\\Image\\" + splitString[1]);
```

The value of _imageName is then stored in a getter called Picture;

Inside my Image class I'm setting the file to be displayed like this:

```
PictureBox _picBox = new PictureBox();
_picBox.Image = Image.FromFile(_tcp.Picture);
```

However, I get the following errors:

> The best overloaded method match for "System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(string) has some invalid arguments
>   Argument 1: cannot convert 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'string;

The line that is highlighted is the _picBox.Image line. I've tried googleing an answer. Casting the command as both an Image and a float, changing my getter. But nothing is working.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what your code does, but seems like this might work: `_picBox.Image = _tcp.Picture;`  put it instead of last line.

Comment: Son of a gun. You are correct. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this lines you are trying to create `Image` form another `Image` instance.

```
 PictureBox _picBox = new PictureBox();
_picBox.Image = Image.FromFile(_tcp.Picture);
```

While `FromFile` method accepts `string` path to image file you want to load.
Fix it like this:

```
 PictureBox _picBox = new PictureBox();
_picBox.Image = _tcp.Picture;
```